# How to add #EXT-X-MAP into .m3u8 in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to create a .m3u8 file with the #EXT-X-MAP and I can't seem to get it to work. What does the EXT-X-MAP element do and how can I add it into my file?

This is my current ffmpeg command to create the segments etc.: `ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -b:a 64k -map 0 -f segment -segment_list_entry_prefix "audio/" -segment_time 10 -segment_list "playlist.m3u8" -segment_format mpegts audio/%03d.ts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EXT-X-MAP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8216#section-4.3.2.5) is used to provide the Media Initialization information, a common sequence needed to parse the segments.

In FFmpeg this is required and used when the segment type is set to fragmented MP4 (`-hls_segment_type fmp4`).

For MPEG-TS this should contain the PAT/PMT packets but I don't think it's implemented. The muxer will just create self-initialized segments, that is the PAT/PMT are repeated at each segment start.